# How to start Azure function locally and attach debugger to process dynamically via launch.json and tasks.json?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

Using .NET Core on a Mac with Visual Studio Code, I'm trying to host an Azure Function locally, and attach the debugger to it.
Manually, I can get it to work by starting the function with `func host start`, followed by pressing the debug button in the IDE, which runs the default launch.json file. This let's me pick a process to attach the debugger to because of the line `"processId": "${command:pickProcess}"`.

I would like to automize this flow, triggering it with a simple click on the debug button in VSCode.

[image: launch- and tasks.json]

In the above picture I attempt to solve this by running a `preLaunchTask` before attaching the debugger. This task should host and start the function - which it does so successfully when isolated from the flow.
However, when I hit the Debug button with the above configuration, VSCode lets me pick a process immediately before actually having completed the `preLaunchTask` and so the process `func` is not yet available.

Is my line of thinking in order?
What could I be missing in order for this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try to [create the local Functions app with the Visual Studio Code Functions extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/tutorial-vscode-serverless-node-create-local?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203). When you created the Functions app with the extension, it automatically adds a VS Code launch configuration to your project which at least works on my machine :-).

One difference between my and your configuration is the processId which you might change to this:
`"processId": "${command:azureFunctions.pickProcess}"`

Comment: Or simply remove the .vscode-folder, restart visual code and allow it to re-create those files as they should look like. Those files easily get messed up if you move files around etc.

Comment: They also get easily messed up by just using the Azure Functions extension in VS Code. From experience, it generates broken configurations more often than it creates working ones. I concluded it's not worth it and uninstalled it, creating the configurations manually according to documentation is much faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 5):

The VSCode Function extension works like a charm, the problem is that the team already started on this solution in Visual Studio Windows and so I have to adapt to that.

I did not notice the `azureFunctions` part in the launch configuration that comes with the extension though!
I edited my `launch.json` to the following:

```
{
  "name": "Attach to .NET Functions",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "attach",
  "processId": "${command:azureFunctions.pickProcess}"
}
```

which seemed to do the trick! Notice that there's no `preLaunchTask` anymore. However, the host gets started, and the debugger gets attached!
Thanks @MartinBrandl !

Comment: You are welcome! Glad that you were able to solve it. BR

Answer (score 0):

The previous solutions did not work for me. I had to add the following line to the host start task in `tasks.json`:

```
    "isBackground": true
```

This way the debugger does not wait for the host start task to finish.